# undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/users/sign_out":String (Devise gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In my project i am using `devise` gem .And also using `link_to_if` url helper because when users not isn't signed in , it will provide  `new_user_session_path` and also when they signed in it will provide `destroy_user_session_path`. For this at first I tried this code:

```
  <%=
      link_to_if(current_user.nil?, "Sign in", new_user_session_path) do
        link_to(user_signed_in?, "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete )
      end
  %>
```

its says "wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)"

Then I tried this code:

```
  <%=
      link_to_if(current_user.nil?, "Sign in", new_user_session_path) do
        link_to(user_signed_in?, "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path)
      end
  %>
```

its says "undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/users/sign_out":String"

Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a condition in your `link_to` call, just remove the first argument like this :).

```
link_to("Sign out", destroy_user_session_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I want to use link_to_if helper. using if/else statement I done that successfully. Please tell me, is there any way except this?? Please :(

Comment: You're already using it. I'm referring to the `link_to` call in the block. Or am I not getting your question correctly?

Comment: will you please tell me, How can I add "sign up" link  beside "sign in" link. I tried this code <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> or <%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>. But now I want to add it with link_to_if helper.

Comment: I don't think using `link_to_if` suits your case now, because it returns something eventually either a link or a plain name, so I guess you'll need to use an if statement instead.